# Configure Aptana Studio 3 with Local IIS Server

Tags: iis, aptana, web-deployment

I am very new to web development and so I am also very new to Aptana Studio and IIS.  I just installed both on my computer today.  I read instructions on Aptana Studio's help system about adding a web server, but it does not seem to work for IIS.

I have IIS 7 running locally on my machine.  In Aptana, I went to Servers --> Add Server --> Simple Web Server.  Then I gave it the following parameters in the dialog:

```
Name: IIS
URL: http://localhost:80
Document Root: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

The server then appeared in the Servers View, but status was N/A and the preview of any website would still use the built in web server included with Aptana.

My Google searching has not found any more specific instructions for configuring Aptana with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success by going to the Debug Configurations, from there you can switch the launch location (and browser executable) with a combination of radio buttons.  To access the menu, click on the pull down next to the debug button.

Comment: Does the project have to be in the wwwroot directory?